# sql compare dynamic count value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, compare

first of all this is just a test table, i want to learn some sql queries.
I want to know who has booked the same flight (starts in münchen) as often as 'peter' did.
the query that gives me the right result is:

```
SELECT r1.vorname
FROM (
SELECT p1.vorname, count(p1.passnr) as anzahl
FROM passagier p1, teilnehmer t1, abflug a
WHERE a.abflug = 'münchen'
AND t1.flugnr = a.flugnr
AND t1.passnr = p1.passnr
group by p1.passnr ) as r1,
(
SELECT p1.vorname, count(p1.passnr) as anzahl
FROM passagier p1, teilnehmer t1, abflug a
WHERE a.abflug = 'münchen'
AND t1.flugnr = a.flugnr
AND t1.passnr = p1.passnr
group by p1.passnr ) as r2

WHERE r2.vorname = 'peter'
AND r1.vorname != 'peter'
AND r1.anzahl = r2.anzahl
```

is there a better query to get the same result?

```
--
-- Table structure for table `abflug`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `abflug` (
  `flugnr` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `zielkrz` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ziel` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `abflkrz` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `abflug` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`flugnr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `abflug`
--

INSERT INTO `abflug` (`flugnr`, `zielkrz`, `ziel`, `abflkrz`, `abflug`) VALUES
('ba921', 'fra', 'frankfurt', 'muc', 'münchen'),
('lh807', 'nrt', 'tokyo narita', 'fra', 'frankfurt'),
('lh808', 'fra', 'frankfurt', 'kix', 'osaka kansai'),
('lh809', 'kix', 'osaka kansai', 'fra', 'frankfurt');


--
-- Table structure for table `passagier`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `passagier` (
  `passnr` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `vorname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`passnr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `passagier`
--

INSERT INTO `passagier` (`passnr`, `vorname`, `name`) VALUES
('10118', 'gerhard', 'schröder'),
('10120', 'peter', 'müller'),
('10123', 'angela', 'merkel'),
('10999', 'aryan', 'layes'),
('11000', 'jessica', 'alba');

--
-- Table structure for table `teilnehmer`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teilnehmer` (
  `flugnr` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `passnr` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `datum` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`flugnr`,`passnr`,`datum`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `teilnehmer`
--

INSERT INTO `teilnehmer` (`flugnr`, `passnr`, `datum`) VALUES
('ba921', '10120', '20.1.2012'),
('ba921', '10120', '23.1.2012'),
('ba921', '10123', '20.1.2012'),
('ba921', '10999', '20.1.2012'),
('ba921', '10999', '23.1.2012'),
('ba921', '11000', '23.1.2012'),
('lh807', '10118', '20.1.2012'),
('lh807', '10120', '20.1.2012'),
('lh807', '10123', '20.1.2012'),
('lh808', '10118', '27.3.2012'),
('lh808', '10120', '23.1.2012'),
('lh808', '10123', '23.1.2012'),
('lh809', '10120', '23.1.2012');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more efficient ways.  The following query calculates the information for Peter in a subquery, joining that to the rest of the query:

```
select allp.*
from (SELECT p.passnr, count(p1.passnr) as anzahl
      FROM passagier p join
           teilnehmer t
           on t.passnr = p.passnr join
           abflug a
           on t.flugnr = a.flugnr
      where a.abflug = 'münchen'
      group by p.passnr
     ) allp cross join
     (SELECT count(p1.passnr) as anzahl
      FROM passagier p join
           teilnehmer t
           on t.passnr = p.passnr join
           abflug a
           on t.flugnr = a.flugnr 
      where a.abflug = 'münchen' AND
            p.vorname = 'peter'
      limit 1
     ) peter
where allp.forname <> 'peter' and allp.anzahl >= peter.anzahl
```

The use of "limit" is just in case there is more than one Peter in the data.

You can also use the "with" statement to simplify this:

```
with allp as (
      SELECT count(p1.passnr) as anzahl
      FROM passagier p join
           teilnehmer t
           on t.passnr = p.passnr join
           abflug a
           on t.flugnr = a.flugnr 
      where a.abflug = 'münchen'
     ) allp 
select *
from allp
where allp.forname <> 'peter' and
      allp.anzahl >= (select anzahl from allp where vorname = 'peter' limit 1)
```

This version summarizes all the data by passenger.  It then chooses the ones where the "anzahl" is greater than Peter's.  In mysql, the first version is likely to perform better, because the subquery in the WHERE clause will (probably) be evaluated on every row.